# How to set replication on Rdkafka for dot net client?

Tags: .net, kafka-consumer-api

How to set replication for three broker on Rdkafka for dot C# net client?

Answer (score 0):

No need to setup much in RdKafka, it will use replication as configured on the brokers/per topic. If you connect to one out of the three brokers it'll query for the others and connect to them as well.

Optionally you can pass them all in the broker list by passing all brokers separated by commas, e.g. `var producer = new Producer("broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092")`.

Comment: Actually I have three broker and I want to send data only at one server.I want that my kafka server will replicate that data on my other two server.Right now my .net client  create connections to all broker and sending data to each broker which is effecting the performance.

Comment: It already does exactly this. For each partition there's exactly one leader and your .net client will send each message that you produce only to that one leader. Then the leader distributes that message to the other brokers as necessary.

Maybe you have multiple partitions in your topic? Then there will be multiple leaders, one per partition, and the client will send different messages to different brokers.